# Why is my JSON array prototype mapping not working?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to map the array in my JSON file but I'm doing something wrong and I can't figure out what. When I do console.log the result is "undefined". I have the feeling that the error might be in my JSON file and not necessarily in the .map function but I can't figure it out.

this is my JSON file:

```
{
  "homepage": {
    "servicios": {
      "subheader": "Servicios",
      "title": "Áreas de Práctica",
      "cards": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "title": "Empresarial",
          "body": "lorem ipsum"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "title": "Protección de datos personales",
          "body": "lorem ipsum"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "title": "Penal",
          "body": "lorem ipsum"
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "title": "Laboral",
          "body": "lorem ipsum"
        },
        {
          "id": "5",
          "title": "Migratorio",
          "body": "lorem ipsum"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is my code:

```
import { Container, Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import texts from "../../text/global.json";

function CardDeck() {
  const cards = [texts.homepage.servicios.cards];
  return (
    <>
          <Row>
            {cards.map((card) => {
              return <div>{card.title}</div>;
            })}
          </Row>
    </>
  );
}

export default CardDeck;
```

I use the .map function but I'm not sure I'm using it correctly. I'm guessing that probably is the way my JSON file is written. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
const cards = texts.homepage.servicios.cards;
```

instead of

```
const cards = [texts.homepage.servicios.cards];
```

you are basically mapping inside a nested array, this way you'll have to map cards[0], so it'll be

```
{cards[0].map((card) => {
     return <div>{card.title}</div>;
})}
```

Comment: There's already an answer explaining that.

Comment: Well I'm sorry, I did not refresh the page. I hope both of the answers helped him out though!

Answer (score 3):

`texts.homepage.servicios.cards` is already referencing an array, and you're putting it into an array:

```
const cards = [texts.homepage.servicios.cards];
```

So `cards` is indeed an array, and you are successfully calling `.map()` on it.  But that array contains only one element, which itself is an array and has no `title` property.  It basically looks like this:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Empresarial",
      "body": "lorem ipsum"
    },
    //... etc.
  ]
]
```

Just reference the array itself:

```
const cards = texts.homepage.servicios.cards;
```